# What does “switch off” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I read a [blog post](http://angusferraro.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/work-life-balance-of-a-phd-student-an-experiment/) which includes the following sentence:

> I hear many PhD students say they feel stressed because they can’t switch off.

What does the term *switch off* mean in the sentence above?

I guess it means a person switching between different status, but still I need your confirmation.

Comment: 'get their minds off the demands their positions make on them, and relax - with friends / a good book / a glass of ruby ale; to watch a film / football match ...'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks, Edwin. Seemed my guessing is wrong.

Comment: Before asking here, you should at least check a [dictionary or two](http://www.onelook.com/?w=switch+off&ls=a). Then, if you're still confused, you should include the definitions you found, and explain why you're still confused. Questions here are expected to be asked with a least a modicum of research done first. Also, if you're confused about simple idioms such as _switch off_, you might want to try the site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions), although the same protocol of "research first - then ask" applies there as well as here.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks, J.R. You provide me a great dictionary link.Very useful. I'm a new English learner. Seemed I should post my questions on ELL.

Comment: @nn0p: Hope to see you over there :^) Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/switch-off#switch-off_5), *switch off* > *to stop listening to someone, or to stop thinking about something*

In your context, the PhD students get stressed because they never get time to stop thinking about their work.

[Here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/switch) are some other idioms and phrases associated with the word switch like switch on, switch out, switch around etc..